# Unable to dissolve adjacent faces after Boolean modifier on cylinder

Tags: boolean-modifier

After applying a boolean modifier on a cylinder by using another cylinder as the object, I get the desired hole in the middle, but it created a couple of weird diagonal edges on the top and bottom of the cylinder. So I deleted those 2 edges and then bridged the inner and outer edge loops of the cylinder. This creates a lot of faces on the side which I don't want. I only want the entire side to have one face. So I select all the faces of the side and **right click -> Dissolve faces**. Nothing happens. But if I leave just one face and select all the others, they get dissolved into a single face. This leaves the cylinder side with a big face almost 90% of the area, and a tiny face. Why is this behavior happening and **why can't I make all these faces fuse into one face**?

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AMBAPwqIRFiHb8VcnxYNLBCyvj2Uf5dD/view?usp=share_link

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You mean you want the whole thing to be 1 face? You cannot have holes in faces in blender. Read https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/precision_drawing_tools/holes_in_faces.html

Comment: If you create a hole within a face you need at least 2 edges to connect the inner edge to the outer edge

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie and moonBoots Thank you very much guys. You are right. For whatever reason, I can't see the arrow so sadly cant upvote your comments.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Harry and moonboots in comments, this is the answer if anyone needs it:

You cannot have holes in faces in blender because if you create a hole within a face you need at least 2 edges to connect the inner edge to the outer edge. Read [Blender docs about this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/precision_drawing_tools/holes_in_faces.html).